# Can ROS2 run on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: ros2, raspberrypi, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm curious what the potential is for ROS2 to run on the Raspberry Pi Zero W. I have installed Arch on the pi zero. Does anyone know if these instructions would work?  https://github.com/ros2-for-arm/ros2/wiki/ROS2-on-arm-architecture

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299588/can-ros2-run-on-raspberry-pi-zero-w/) by [austinstig](https://answers.ros.org/users/36818/austinstig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-08-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you cross-compile ROS2 using the above link, you might need to meet some library dependencies but it should work as is.

---

Originally posted by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) with karma: 527 on 2018-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1